# Getting 405 (Method Not Allowed) while reading rss feed in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, rss

I am developing a chrome extension using AngularJs. Plugin will mainly read a rss feed and display posts. I am getting following two errors.

- **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)**
- **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?q=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.nraboy.com%2Ffeed%2F&v=1.0. Invalid HTTP status code 405**

My code is as following.

```
var appController = angular.module('appController',[]);

appController.controller('homeController',['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){

     $http.get("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load",{ params: { "v": "1.0", "q": "http://blog.nraboy.com/feed/" } })
            .success(function(data) {

                console.log(JSON.stringify(data.responseData.feed.entries))
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + data);

            });

    }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do `jsonp` call instead of `.get`. As it seems different domain from which you wanted to get data. And while doing `JSONP` call do pass `callback` parameter with value `JSON_CALLBACK`(or anything), that will just wrap up retrieved data with the name of `JSON_CALLBACK(data)`

```
$http.jsonp("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load", {
    params: {
      "v": "1.0",
      "q": "http://blog.nraboy.com/feed/",
      callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.feeds = response.data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data.responseData.feed.entries))
  }, function(data) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + data);
  })
```

[**Demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/OtVZsCSeJe0VzOKsMqIk?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Pankaj you saved the day!

Comment: @JayPoojara Glad to know that it helped. Thanks :)